# Creating Web Service Client from WSDL always SOAPFault

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to call SOAP service from WSDL on my client apps. I generate the required classes from WSDL using `wsimport` command.

```
wsimport -keep -verbose <wsdladdress>
```

then i created a base class that will be a mapper to the wsdl (endpoint, authorization, etc)

**BaseService.java**

```
public abstract class BaseService {
    private String wsUsername = "";
    private String wsPassword = "";

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseService.class);

    protected Emoneytopup emoneyTopup = new Emoneytopup();
    protected TopupWebService topupWebService;

    public static String END_POINT_TARGET_TOPUP = "";

    public BaseService(){
        try{
            wsUsername = PropertiesHandler.getPromoEngineProperties().getProperty("topupUsername");
            wsPassword = PropertiesHandler.getPromoEngineProperties().getProperty("topupPassword");
            END_POINT_TARGET_TOPUP = PropertiesHandler.getPromoEngineProperties().getProperty("topupEndPoint");
            String wsAuth = (wsUsername.length()>0&&wsPassword.length()>0) ? this.wsUsername + ":" + this.wsPassword : "";

            // Authentication header
            Map headers = new HashMap<>();
            //headers.put("Authorization", Collections.singletonList("Basic " + new BASE64Encoder().encode(auth.getBytes())));
            headers.put("Authorization", Collections.singletonList("Basic " + wsAuth.getBytes()));

            // TopUp Web Service
            this.topupWebService = this.emoneyTopup.getEmoneytopupPort();
            ((BindingProvider)this.topupWebService).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address", END_POINT_TARGET_TOPUP);
            ((BindingProvider)this.topupWebService).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.http.request.headers", headers);
        } catch(IOException ie){
            logger.error("Cannot get variables from properties file");
        }   
    }

    protected void printInMessage(Class c, Object o) {
        try {
            Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { c }).createMarshaller();
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(o, stringWriter);
            String trxContent = stringWriter.toString();

            logger.debug(trxContent);
            //this.loggingService.saveMsgIn("", "WS", trxContent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e, e);
        }
    }

    protected void printInMessage(Object o) {
        printInMessage(o.getClass(), o);
    }

    protected void printOutMessage(Class c, Object o) {
        try {
            Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { c }).createMarshaller();
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(o, stringWriter);
            String trxContent = stringWriter.toString();

            logger.debug(trxContent);
            //this.loggingService.saveMsgOut("", "WS", trxContent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.logger.error(e, e);
        }
    }

    protected void printOutMessage(Object o) {
        printOutMessage(o.getClass(), o);
    } 

    protected <T> T getValue(JAXBElement<T> jaxbe) {
        if(jaxbe != null)
            return jaxbe.getValue();
        return null;
    }
}
```

then, i made another class, `ESCreditRunner.java`, that extends the mapper class above.

**ESCreditRunner.java**

```
public class ESCreditRunner extends BaseService{
    private File statusFile;
    private Properties status;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ESCreditRunner.class);
    public ESCreditRunner(File stFile, Properties st){
        this.statusFile = stFile;
        this.status = st;
    }

    public ESCreditRunner(){}
    public void testCall(){
        System.out.println("Attempting to run testCall()..");
        TopupInquiryRequest request = new TopupInquiryRequest();
        this.topupWebService.inquiry(request);
    }
}
```

and here's the simple class that calls ESCreditRunner class

**EngineRunner.java**

```
public class EngineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EngineRunner.class); 
    private static File queriesFile;
    private static Properties queries;
    private static File statusFile;
    private static Properties status;
    private static ESClient esClient = new ESTransportClient();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        logger.info("Promo Engine started by Scheduler..");
        ESCreditRunner cRunner = new ESCreditRunner();
        cRunner.testCall();
    }

}
```

when i run that main class, with debugging mode on the server apps (on the TopUpWebService as you can see above), the request didn't reach the server. and i also get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Server error: unexpected-error
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.inquiry(Unknown Source)
    at com.ptdam.promo.services.ESCreditRunner.testCall(ESCreditRunner.java:64)
    at com.ptdam.promo.runners.EngineRunner.main(EngineRunner.java:44)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Server error: unexpected-error
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1667)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1520)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1428)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:658)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    ... 3 more
```

what causes this error, how can i figure it out, and what's the solution? 
any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Try defining these props in your main class and see if you can get a more detailed error:`System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");`

Comment: You can also go through this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741313/how-to-convert-a-pfx-file-into-jks-and-then-use-it-to-sign-an-outgoing-soap-requ)